# e.preventdefault on submitting the triggered submit not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-validate

problem is when i click the button whole page refresh, which certainly i do not want as i am trying to submit the form through Ajax.

```
    $('#createFormBtn').on('click', function(e){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
           e.preventDefault();
        $('#block-validate').trigger('submit',function(e){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
           e.preventDefault();
        });
        var formData = {
            FormName : $("#cFormName").val(),
            FormPath :   $("#cFormPath").val(),
            FormCIPath : $("#cFormCIPath").val(),
            TabID : $('#selectTab').val(),
            TabName : $('#selectTabName div.select2-container a.select2-choice span.select2-chosen').text(),
            MenuOrder : $('#selectMenuOrder div.select2-container a.select2-choice span.select2-chosen').text(),
            IsMenuLink : isMenuLink_createForm
        };
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"{{base_url()}}admin/configurations/addNewForm/",
            data: formData/*,
            success: function(output){
                if (output == true){
                    oTable.fnReloadAjax();
                }
            }*/
        });

    });
```

i added this code

```
$('#block-validate').trigger('submit',function(e){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
           e.preventDefault();
        });
```

because i need to Trigger the `Submit`, As the validation in my Form will not work. This Button is not inside the `<form>` tags.

But now it is giving the problem as if i click this button whole page refresh..

**HTML** if anyone wants to see..

```
<div id="addNewFormModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><i style='color: #666666' class='fa fa-edit fa-fw fa-1x'></i>Edit</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="body collapse in" id="div-1">
                            <form class="form-horizontal" id="block-validate">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-lg-4" for="text1">Form Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="formName" placeholder="Form Name" id="cFormName">
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-lg-4" for="pass1">Form Path</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="formPath" placeholder="Form Path" id="cFormPath">
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Form CI Path</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="formCIPath" placeholder="Form CI Path" id="cFormCIPath">
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->

                                <div class="form-group" id="selectTab_MainDiv">
                                    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Select Tab</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8" id="selectTabName">
                                        <input type='hidden' class="required" name='selectTab' id='selectTab'/>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Have Parent</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8" id="haveParentDiv">
                                        <input class="make-switch" id="haveParent" type="checkbox" data-on-color="success" data-on-text="Yes" data-off-text="NO" data-off-color="danger">
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.row --><!-- /.row -->

                                <div class="form-group" id="selectParentMenu_MainDiv" style="display: none">
                                    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Parent Form</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8" id="selectParentMenuDiv">
                                        <input type='hidden' name='input' id='selectParentMenu'/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group" id="selectTab_MainDiv">
                                    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Menu Order</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8" id="selectMenuOrder">
                                        <select class="commonGeneralSelect2 required" name="selectMenuOrder">
                                            <option></option>
                                            <option value="1">1</option>
                                            <option value="2">2</option>
                                            <option value="3">3</option>
                                            <option value="4">4</option>
                                            <option value="5">5</option>
                                            <option value="6">6</option>
                                            <option value="7">7</option>
                                            <option value="8">8</option>
                                            <option value="9">9</option>
                                            <option value="10">10</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Show on Menu</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8" id="isMenuLink_createSwitchDiv">
                                        <input class="make-switch" id="isMenuLink_createSwitch" type="checkbox" data-on-color="success" data-on-text="Yes" data-off-text="NO" data-off-color="danger">
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.row --><!-- /.row -->
                                {{*<input type="submit" value="Validate" class="btn btn-primary">*}}
                            </form>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="createFormBtn">Create</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal --><!-- /#Edit Button Modal -->
```

Comment: you never stopped the propagation/default of the original click on your #createFormBtn. You've only stopped it on your #block-validate

Comment: @MarcB
i didn't added the propagation/default to that button in first place cuz that button was not causing the refresh..only this trigger is causing the page refresh, but now as you have mentioned i added propagation/default to both inside `#block-validate` function and `#createFormBtn` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace all this...

```
$('#block-validate').trigger('submit',function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

with only this...

```
$('#block-validate').valid();
```

---

There is no need to trigger a submit to get the form to validate when you can simply use [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/).  It will trigger validation without submitting the form.  (You should edit your OP to mention the jQuery Validate plugin and show the code.)

---

**EDIT**:

Actually, your `ajax()` should really be within the `submitHandler` callback of the `.validate()` method.  [As per documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler), it's *"the right place to submit a form via Ajax..."*.

So instead of the simple suggestion I made above, do this instead...

```
// click handler is needed since this button is not a 'submit' type button
$('#createFormBtn').on('click', function(e){

    // block default action of button click
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    // submit the form -> will validate AUTOMATICALLY
    $('#block-validate').submit();

});
```

and put the `ajax` in the `submitHandler` callback within *your* `.validate()` method...

```
$('#block-validate').validate({
    // your other rules and options here,
    submitHandler: function(form) {  // only fires on valid form
        var formData = {
            FormName : $("#cFormName").val(),
            FormPath :   $("#cFormPath").val(),
            FormCIPath : $("#cFormCIPath").val(),
            TabID : $('#selectTab').val(),
            TabName : $('#selectTabName div.select2-container a.select2-choice span.select2-chosen').text(),
            MenuOrder : $('#selectMenuOrder div.select2-container a.select2-choice span.select2-chosen').text(),
            IsMenuLink : isMenuLink_createForm
        };
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"{{base_url()}}admin/configurations/addNewForm/",
            data: formData
        });
    }
});
```

Please note that most people use [jQuery `.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) instead of manually creating an array with every field attached to a `.val()`.

```
data:  $(form).serialize()
```

Comment: Thanks, hmmm. i thought you were referring to the .validate(), cuz i already had `.validate` in my js file , but i didn't knew about `.valid`.
Also i checked the documentation link u gave for ajax, Thank-you its a nice info and i will try that also.

Comment: Thankyou sir. Im using select2, will the .serialize gonna work with the select2 library.

Im using select 2 as for dropdowns in my form.

Comment: @SizzlingCode, I don't know, but if it doesn't, you could easily concatenate the `select2` data onto the `.serialize()` array.

Answer (score 0):

You are manually triggering a form submit:

```
 $('#block-validate').trigger('submit',function(e){
       e.stopImmediatePropagation();
       e.preventDefault();
 });
```

as `#block-validate` is your form element.

You are trying to submit your form via ajax, so there is absolutely no reason to trigger a form submit manually. Just remove this block, make your ajax request and the form will be posted.

Also note that the `e` variable in your `trigger` function is not the form-submit event you expect it to be, check the manual on [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: The OP already explained that he needs to do this in order to trigger validation.  I agree though, this is a hacky way to trigger validation.  Surely, the validation would have another method he could use.

Comment: Yes, you are right it do post, but as i already have said i do need to trigger the submit because the form will not validate. i am using jquery validate library, which need one to submit the form.

Comment: @SizzlingCode, if you're using the jQuery Validate plugin, just call the `.valid()` method to manually trigger validation on the form.  **There is no need to trigger the `submit` event at all**.

Comment: @Sparky Yes, you are right, on both counts. I missed the bit about the jQuery validation plugin though...

Comment: @Sparky
Sir, if you have any other good solution for submit the button while outside the form tags, please tell so that this page dont refresh.
All the Problem i have is the form do submit without refresh and validation should work.

Comment: @Sparky
I already have tried not triggering the submit, but it dont work :(

Comment: @SizzlingCode It seems the solution has already been posted, trigger / activate the validation, not a form submit.

Comment: @SizzlingCode How / with what are you validating your form?

Comment: @SizzlingCode, I posted an answer.  Please respond to my answer if you have questions.  Also, update/edit your OP to include the jQuery Validate code, since the only clue to that critical detail is buried in these comments.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you even trigger the submit at all? Purely for the form validation?

You'll need to really recreate that validation.. the problem is you're unbinding the validation completely when you use `preventDefault()` and `stopImmediatePropogation()` below:

```
$('#block-validate').trigger('submit',function(e){
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

You really want to just re-validate the form (this is pseudo code which almost surely will not work). I cannot tell what is being used to validate your form above, but if you provide I will edit my answer for you.

```
$('#createFormBtn').on('click', function(e){
     $('#block-validate').validate() 
     //continue with rest of form submission
```

Comment: The `.validate()` method is for _initializing_ the plugin... NOT for validating the form.  He mentioned the jQuery Validate plugin in a comment on another answer.